# can't access remote connections in SQL Server 2008 from client side

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have installed sql server 2008 r2 data engine and Management studio on my machine, and on the same machine i setup windows 7 in virtual box then setup sql server 2008 r2 Client Native and Management studio and i followed this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx), but every time i try to connect to my machine by ip like this:
[image]
i don't know what i missing, i start to doubt with virtual box, so how to make the connection

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you can ping your SQL server PC from the VM
2. Make sure you can connect locally to the SQL server instance from the PC with SQL installed
3. Make sure the 'Sql Server Browser' service is running on the SQL server machine

Comment: how can i make sure i can ping my SQL server PC from the VM?

Comment: can you give me any videos or steps for that

Comment: open up command prompt on the VM. (cmd.exe)
type
`ping <server name that's running SQL>`

Comment: it couldn't find host

Comment: Sounds like the problem doesn't relate to SQL then, it's down to the fact your networking within the VM environment isn't correct. Check the VM networking documentation for your software, and make sure firewalls are disabled on both the VM and the VM host.

Comment: but it still the same problem